# Can Node.js be used with Express as a static web server in production?

Tags: node.js, express, static, webserver

Can I use Node.js with Express as a static web server? I need to upload new files to static directories based on requests from developers.

Can someone tell me how to do this using Node.js, since mostly we use CloudFoundry to deploy this Node.js app.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

whatever files uploaded inside the public folder are served as static files from your web server and it has nothing to do with deployment.

Comment: what do you meant by nothing to with deployment, how to upload new files to the static server without redeployment ?

Comment: you don't need to redeploy. You can ftp files to cloudfoundry public folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server?rq=1 follow this question gives you more info.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the npm module [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) Serving using express.

This is a simple example of using Express:

```
var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.use(serveStatic('public/ftp', {'index': ['default.html', 'default.htm']}))
app.listen(3000)
```

For uploading files with node.js you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959055/nodejs-amazon-s3-file-upload/36959128#36959128)

Comment: thanks for answering, its not about serving static files, if we deploy the server to cloudfoundry, then how can we upload new files to public directory so that new files can be accessed and how to edit old files.